# Insert image as background set it bottom right corner inside Linear Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

I have activity based of vertical `LinearLayout`

Something like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <fragment android:name="com.idatt.activities.TitleBarFragment"
        android:id="@+id/fr_title_bar"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        tools:layout="@layout/title_bar_fragment" />

    <ImageView
        android:background="@drawable/img_logo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:contentDescription="Company logo" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="100dp"
        android:paddingRight="0dp"
        android:paddingStart="100dp"
        android:paddingEnd="0dp">

        <TextView style="@style/MyTextViewLabel"
            android:text="@string/str_under_logo" />

        <TextView android:id="@+id/tv_applicationVersion"
            style="@style/MyTextViewLabel.Black.Data"
            android:textColor="@color/blue_end"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="Version" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        style="@style/MyTextViewLabel"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:text="Ditat Mobile Dispatch is designed for asset-light motor carriers that use independent contractors/owner operators for their power solution"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        android:textSize="14sp"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="@color/blue_end"
        android:padding="5dp">

        <TextView style="@style/MyTextViewLabel"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Serial Number"
            android:textColor="@color/white"/>

        <TextView android:id="@+id/tv_serial_number"
            style="@style/MyTextViewLabel"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="123456789012345"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:textColor="#28cdfb"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bt_openSourceLicenses"
        android:text="Open source licenses"
        android:background="@color/transparent"
        android:textColor="@color/blue_end"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I want to place image as background but it needs to go into right bottom corner. How do I do that?

EDIT:

I tried to do it like this, by wrapping into `FrameLayout` and setting gravity for image but it doesn't put image to the bottom and I still need to know how to align it to the right

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/img_background"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <fragment android:name="com.idatt.activities.TitleBarFragment"
            android:id="@+id/fr_title_bar"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            tools:layout="@layout/title_bar_fragment" />

        <ImageView
            android:background="@drawable/img_logo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:contentDescription="Company logo" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="100dp"
            android:paddingRight="0dp"
            android:paddingStart="100dp"
            android:paddingEnd="0dp">

            <TextView style="@style/MyTextViewLabel"
                android:text="@string/str_under_logo" />

            <TextView android:id="@+id/tv_applicationVersion"
                style="@style/MyTextViewLabel.Black.Data"
                android:textColor="@color/blue_end"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="Version" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            style="@style/MyTextViewLabel"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:text="Ditat Mobile Dispatch is designed for asset-light motor carriers that use independent contractors/owner operators for their power solution"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:paddingBottom="20dp"
            android:textSize="14sp"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:background="@color/blue_end"
            android:padding="5dp">

            <TextView style="@style/MyTextViewLabel"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Serial Number"
                android:textColor="@color/white"/>

            <TextView android:id="@+id/tv_serial_number"
                style="@style/MyTextViewLabel"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="123456789012345"
                android:textSize="22sp"
                android:textColor="#28cdfb"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bt_openSourceLicenses"
            android:text="Open source licenses"
            android:background="@color/transparent"
            android:textColor="@color/blue_end"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: I'd try using a `RelativeLayout` as the parent...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to wrap it into `RelativeLayout`.

Then in your `ImageView` tag add `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` and `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"` to align it at the bottom right corner.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/img_background"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <fragment android:name="com.idatt.activities.TitleBarFragment"
            android:id="@+id/fr_title_bar"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            tools:layout="@layout/title_bar_fragment" />

        <ImageView
            android:background="@drawable/img_logo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:contentDescription="Company logo" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="100dp"
            android:paddingRight="0dp"
            android:paddingStart="100dp"
            android:paddingEnd="0dp">

            <TextView style="@style/MyTextViewLabel"
                android:text="@string/str_under_logo" />

            <TextView android:id="@+id/tv_applicationVersion"
                style="@style/MyTextViewLabel.Black.Data"
                android:textColor="@color/blue_end"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="Version" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            style="@style/MyTextViewLabel"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:text="Ditat Mobile Dispatch is designed for asset-light motor carriers that use independent contractors/owner operators for their power solution"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:paddingBottom="20dp"
            android:textSize="14sp"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:background="@color/blue_end"
            android:padding="5dp">

            <TextView style="@style/MyTextViewLabel"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Serial Number"
                android:textColor="@color/white"/>

            <TextView android:id="@+id/tv_serial_number"
                style="@style/MyTextViewLabel"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="123456789012345"
                android:textSize="22sp"
                android:textColor="#28cdfb"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bt_openSourceLicenses"
            android:text="Open source licenses"
            android:background="@color/transparent"
            android:textColor="@color/blue_end"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Rami, Still same issue. Image is not alighning to bottom. It displays right below last button for some reason

Comment: Fixed. I needed to add scale attribute to image